# How to configure windows server to allow local acces and secure RDP

Tags: windows, networking, remote-desktop, windows-server-2008-r2

Since yesterday I'm running windows server 2012. Now I've got 2 questions:

- I'm running sabnzbd on that server and when I want to connect to the server on my laptop via chrome. I type the ip:port in my webbrowser the page doesn't load. Do I need to configure something on the server?
- I normally use linux so now that I got windows I've got the possibility to use the build in RDP. This isn't over a secure line I read. I just don't find a tutorial on how to achieve that it is secure.

Can someone point me in the right direction here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Most likely your Windows Server Firewall does not have any exceptions for the port you are trying to connect to.
2. RDP can be secure/encrypted using Network Level Authentication (NLA). See http://www.howtogeek.com/175087/how-to-enable-and-secure-remote-desktop-on-windows/ and https://security.berkeley.edu/node/94?destination=node/94